# How to detect the device name for a capture device?

Tags: c++, winapi, directshow, gstreamer

I am writing a GStreamer application (GStreamer uses DirectShow under the hood on Windows) that captures a computer's microphone and videocamera. It works fine, but requires me to specify the device names manually. I would like to have my program detect these automatically. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Does it not allow you to enumerate such devices?

Comment: could you give a sample command line that "works fine" for example sake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would surprise me if GStreamer doesn't have capabilities to enumerate devices, but DirectShow definitely has.

See the article on [using the system device enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407292%28VS.85%29.aspx) and use it with the correct [filter categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375655%28VS.85%29.aspx)  - in your case `CLSID_AudioInputDeviceCategory` and `CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use GStreamer's probing interface which allows you to list all possible values for a given property, in your case 'device-name'.

Here is an example:

```
GList* 
gst_camera_capturer_enum_devices(gchar* device_name)
{
  GstElement* device; 
  GstPropertyProbe* probe;
  GValueArray* va; 
  GList* list=NULL; 
  guint i=0; 

  device = gst_element_factory_make (device_name, "source");
  gst_element_set_state(device, GST_STATE_READY);
  gst_element_get_state(device, NULL, NULL, 5 * GST_SECOND);
  if (!device || !GST_IS_PROPERTY_PROBE(device))
    goto finish;
  probe = GST_PROPERTY_PROBE (device);
  va = gst_property_probe_get_values_name (probe, "device-name");
  if (!va)
    goto finish;
  for(i=0; i < va->n_values; ++i) {
    GValue* v = g_value_array_get_nth(va, i);
    list = g_list_append(list, g_string_new(g_value_get_string(v)));
  }
  g_value_array_free(va);

finish:
  {
    gst_element_set_state (device, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT (device));
    return list;
  }
}

GList* 
gst_camera_capturer_enum_video_devices(void)
{
  return gst_camera_capturer_enum_devices("dshowvideosrc"); 
}

GList* 
gst_camera_capturer_enum_audio_devices(void)
{ 
  return gst_camera_capturer_enum_devices("dshowaudiosrc"); 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be probing `"device"` instead of `"device-name"`?

Comment: Apparently on alsa and pulse sinks, you need to probe `device`, while on DirectShow you need to probe `device-name`? Argh.