# Get Gstreamer camera names and ID WINDOWS

Tags: c++, windows, camera, gstreamer

I use GStreamer on Windows VS 2010 and need a pair Camera names - camera ID. Like logitech ... - sdjvnskj (or any other way to have an ID for a camera) and ID should be like in Linux /dev/video0,1 ... . I'm using the ways like ylatuya offerd [How to detect the device name for a capture device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160889/how-to-detect-the-device-name-for-a-capture-device) but it returns half of a string Ok - "USB" and half - UTF unreadable rubish (or mayb) like "\xe0Y\xd2". I have some examples from Linux where after it they create a pipeline like

```
GstElement *pipeline = gst_parse_launch("dshowvideosrc device-name="+ gst_camera_capturer_enum_video_devices() +"name=source1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! fakesink", NULL);
```

but in device-name they write "/dev/video" and I don't know what to write for it. Also how to add to gchar something from GList? I just then need to get resolutions and framerates for each cameras.

Comment: Another question. Is it possible to choose anyhow what camera we use? I mean that I didn't find anywhere any difference between camera names in win device manager. ylatuya's program returns different values for different cameras but when putting them to dshowvideosrc device-name= _his's value_name=... ! fakesink it shows same resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. If it's needed to anybody except me than the pair like in linux ID ("/dev/video0") and normal name is a bit difficult to get. In my case it shows only "USB-video device" for all cameras which is as I understand an ID and the symbolic name at the same time. Just put it to device-name=

`in GstElement *pipeline = gst_parse_launch(`

like above and you have the right camera that you need. The question here is :

"**Does win differs cameras by anything except it's path or ID in dshow???**".

Also I write in Russian OS and with Russian VS 2010 so the question is

**how to print everything in Russian if in the line "USB-video device" USB prints ok and the rest, which is in Russian, is a useless line of some strange symbols?**

But when I print it to a file it's ok.